# How to graph a discontinuous array of data

Tags: plotting, data, list-manipulation, intervals, graphics

I have an array of data, I am trying to plot it but I need to draw a line each 10 data and displayed as a discontinuous function.
I tried using `ListLinePlot` but this joins all the data, not in intervals of 10 as I want it. The array has a large amount of data.

**Could you help me please?**

Comment: Please include the code you tried and the problem you encountered so that readers can  reproduce and solve your problem.

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) the data

```
SeedRandom[1234];

data = RandomReal[10, 40];

ListLinePlot@Partition[Transpose[{Range[Length[data]], data}], 10]
```

[image]

```
data2 = Sort@RandomReal[10, {40, 2}];

ListLinePlot@Partition[data2, 10]
```

[image]